# Python GUI framework to just draw on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, canvas, drawing, drawable

I need a framework that allows to draw in the window canvas (also put images) similar to GDI. Any suggestions? Should be cross platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, by default, comes with [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) for Python 3 and [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tk.html) for Python 2. You can use the Canvas class to draw geometry and images.